# WampServer HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, python, wamp, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project which is a sensor system. The sensors are based on Raspberry Pi and the web application to collect and display information in based on PHP.

I have setup Wamp Server on my laptop, as well as the school's desktop computer. I am running Windows 8 while the school is running Windows 7. Lets just say my school's network is "SIT.edu".

I have a WebS.php file I want the Raspberry Pi python scripts to access. Using the school's desktop computer (IP address e.g. 172.20.1.73), the Raspberry Pi is able to access that file located in the C:\wamp directory and run a function.

However, when I connect to the school network (SIT.edu) with my laptop via and LAN cable, and providing the IP address (e.g. 172.20.1.74) to the python script of Raspberry Pi, the console on Raspberry Pi gives an error of HTTP 403 Forbidden. I have tried disabling firewall but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could it be that the port in the pi is in use by another service? Try using another port number.

Comment: @fp - Hi, when specifying the path, no port number is specified for the desktop computer or my laptop. It's specified as http://172.20.1.74/webS.php

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue. make sure the file has the correct permissions for the user that is connecting to the server.

Comment: it works for me thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677037/wampserver-http-403-forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Apache.

Edit the htpd.conf file. In there is some syntax that tells Apache what locations ( ip address's ) it is allowed to accept connections from.

As its designed to be a development system, by default this is set to only allow acess from the PC running WAMP(Apache) i.e. localhost 127.0.0.1 and maybe ::1 depending on the version you are using.

So edit the httpd.conf file ( using the wampmanager menus )

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Find this section

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost
</Directory>
```

You will now need to add the IP or IP's of the machines accessing your Apache web server. Do it like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    Allow from  172.20.1.74
# Or you could allow any ip on a subnet by using just the forst 3 quartiles
#   Allow from 172.20.1
```

If you are using APache 2.4, the syntax changed for this so yo ushould use

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
#   the equivalent of 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    Require local
#   allowing by IP
    Require ip 172.20.1.74
#   or for the whole subnet
    Require ip 172.20.1
```

Please avoid any suggestions to use `Allow from all` I am sure the school does not want you opening another attack vector on their network.